# How can I ask new users to upvote or accept answer?

Tags: discussion

I decided a few weeks ago to answer questions on the WordPress stack exchange. I specially answer questions from beginners, but it seems they never accept, upvote or respond to the answers I post.

I need 50 reputation for commenting, it's quite frustrating to not be able to do that after answering 7 questions, especially when I need the users to clarify something.

So can I ask in my answer something like:

> Could you accept the answer if I answered correctly?

What would you suggest to earn some reputation while answering to easy questions from beginners?

I really feel this reputation system is unfair when answering to new users, as nobody upvote the answers (because it's usually quite simple). I wanted to help people, but it just feels like I'm wasting my time speaking alone :/

I had a hard time finding a title to this question, I'm sorry if it's not representative to what I wanted to ask.

Here is some of my answers to illustrate my loneliness ahah :
[Thread 1](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/341782/acf-repeater-field-need-if-statement-for-if-sub-field-has-content/341792#341792)
[Thread 2](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/341318/how-to-stop-subdirectory-wordpress-install-adding-head-elemets-to-entire-site/341322#341322)
[Thread 3](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/341237/make-the-checkbox-meta-field-checked-by-default/341239#341239)

Comment: This meta post is giving you the boost to pass 50 points. ;-) You can check back with these users via the commenting system and ask them if they are happy with the answer, and if so, mark it as correct. Generally, new users are not always familiar with the lingo even though there is a good guide helping them.

Comment: I'd recommend to not answer low quality questions if you are here for the game. Instead flag them and move on. All three samples should better be asked on Code Review, IMHO.

Comment: Nice, didn't expect meta reputation to count in my WordPress stack reputation :) thank you for the answers!

Comment: @CamilleV. meta reputation NOT count in my WordPress stack reputation.  Christine was said that meta effect (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

New users may not realise they should mark answers as accepted if they accept them, some users don't see the ticket button, some think this isn't a QA site at all but a discussion forum

So:

1. If a user says thank you, you can politely ask them to mark as accepted, e.g. *"You're welcome, if this answers your question could you mark it as the correct answer? It's the big tick under the voting buttons, it'd be a huge help :)"*
2. Good answers can be up-voted by other community members, I've gotten a lot of reputation points on unaccepted answers, and they show up on Google ^_^
3. Some answers just never get accepted, the user solves their problem and never comes back, or they read the answer and forget the site even exists

Comment: btw, if this answers your question could you mark it as the correct answer? It's the big tick under the voting buttons, it'd be a huge help :)

Comment: Ahah thank you for the answer :)